# How do handlers for CtrlEvents work in a multithreaded environment?

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

In a C console application, if I use `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` in my main thread and I have also other threads running, will all threads stop and the handler be executed in a new thread when the event happens? Or is there a way to make only one thread execute the handler and ignore it in the other ones, kinda like `pthread_sigmask` in Unix?

There's not much information on the subject both on StackOverflow and on the internet so I hope this will turn out useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the above.

As described in the [documentation for the handler routine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/handlerroutine):

> When the signal is received, the system creates a new thread in the process to execute the function.

If you need a particular thread to respond to the console control signal, it is your responsibility to write a handler routine to contact that thread, using whatever inter-thread communications method is most appropriate to your code.

It is also your responsibility to ensure that the handler routine is thread-safe, since the existing threads will continue to run as normal while the signal is being processed.

---

Please note that console control signals are not closely analogous to POSIX signals.  For one thing, they generally only affect console applications (a GUI application will not receive console control signals) and for another they are not designed or intended to be used as an IPC mechanism.  Plus, of course, they never interrupt an existing thread.

The Microsoft C runtime does implement C signals, as required by the standard, but these aren't much like POSIX signals either; most notably, they are intra-process only.  As a special case, if you configure a SIGINT handler, it is implemented as a console control handler, but this functionality [is officially unsupported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/signal) and I recommend against using it.

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to use POSIX signals at all, I'd rather learn the Windows way to solve these problems. 
If I wanted threads to terminate gracefully, could sending window messages from the handler to the other threads and then managing the closing procedure from there be a good idea?

Comment: @EärendilBaggins: A better way to signal termination of threads is to use a manual-reset [Event Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682655.aspx), that threads regularly check, and terminate once signaled. You can wait for thread termination calling [WaitForMultipleObjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025.aspx).

Comment: IMO, it is best to use window messages only for threads that naturally have a window message loop, which is generally only the main thread.  For other threads, well, it depends on what they're doing, but an event object (as IInspectable suggests) is often a good general-purpose choice.  APCs can be more elegant, but that depends on what the thread's main loop looks like and they can be a bit harder to get to grips with.

Comment: I'll definitely check out Event Objects, but this leads to another question: what's a situation in which it could be wise to use Window Events for inter-thread/process communication then?

Comment: You mean window messages?  Only in a GUI application, and only to the main thread (which will already have a window message loop).  That's not a hard-and-fast rule, but it is probably best to stick to it until you know what you're doing.